# É possível aplicar efeitos sonoros em hover ou click no css?

Tags: html, css3

Da para transmitir um efeito sonoro ao encostar o mouse em algum objeto, texto etc..?? queria que ao passar o mouse em cima de algum objeto com efeito 'hover' desse um efeito sonoro, sendo qualquer tipo de som que definir, da para aplicar isso com Css? ou só com JS?

```css
.menu{ display:flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.menu > div{ background-color:#09F; 
padding:20px; 
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:10px;
border-radius:30%;
font-weight:bold;
box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.menu > div:hover{ background-color:#0CC;
transform:scale(1.1); 
box-sizing:border-box; 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px #333333;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div>Botão-1</div>
  <div>Botão-2</div>
  <div>Botão-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso não é possível de fazer com `css`, precisa usar `javascript`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outra opção só que ***sem jQuery***. Vc pode declarar uma variável de áudio e definir um `src` com o arquivo do áudio escolhido. Depois no btn vc declara a função js no `mouseover` para tocar o beep tipo assim: `onmouseover="teste.play()"` *OBS: acredito não ser possível de fazer com CSS*

```css
.menu{ display:flex; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
.menu > div{ background-color:#09F; 
padding:20px; 
cursor:pointer;
margin-left:10px;
border-radius:30%;
font-weight:bold;
box-shadow:0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.menu > div:hover{ background-color:#0CC;
transform:scale(1.1); 
box-sizing:border-box; 
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px #333333;}
```

```html
<script>
var teste = new Audio();
teste.src = 'https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-01a.mp3';
</script>

<div class="menu">
  <div onmouseover="teste.play()">SOM</div>
  <div>Botão-2</div>
  <div>Botão-3</div>
</div>
```

Aqui tem mais detalhes: http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Button-Sound-Effects-Tutorial-Audible-Menu-Systems

Comment: Inseri o comando  onmouseover="teste.play()" na 'div' botão-1 do meu código e o som não saiu, estou usando o chrome, o código do outro usuário logo a cima tbm não funcionou

Comment: Acho que tem algum problema, era para funcionar no chrome, mas só funciona daqui mesmo ao executar, copiei seu código e colei em um htm aqui e não executou

Comment: @ElienayJunior cara editei a pergunta e cloquei com o seu código da pergunta e está funcionando normal... Lembre-se que o script do som deve vir dentro do head da página de preferência.

Comment: Funcionou agora, mas quando carrega a página ao encostar o mouse o som não executar, só executa depois de um click em qualquer local da página e depois ao encostar o mouse o som começa, tá igual ao código do outro usuário, mas eu vou marcar sua resposta como valida

Comment: @ElienayJunior da uma olhada no link que eu postei junto com a minha resposta. Lá tem um tutorial simples, e mais detalhes de como fazer dessa forma. Aqui está funcionando normal no Chrome 66, sem precisar clicar em nada antes etc... As vezes algum outro usuária também teste e comenta aqui. Se vc for usar essa solução agradeço pela marcação :)

Comment: @ElienayJunior sobre o som demorar um pouco para tocar é pq ele só é baixado quando vc passa o mouse no elemento a primeira vez. Talvez tenha lguma forma de fazer o "preload" desse audio via JS antes da página terminar de carregar. Infelizmente JS não é minha especialidade rss

Comment: Aguem encontrou a solução? o meu só funciona depois que clicar na pagina. tambem.

Comment: @gessermigueldapaixao leia aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/457623/mp3-n%c3%a3o-funciona-no-javasccript

Answer (score 4):

Acredito não ser possível reproduzir um som apenas com CSS. O som em uma página é executado como um conteúdo, utilizando o elemento `<audio>`. Já o CSS é utilizado apenas para *estilizar* esse conteúdo, portanto não sendo capaz de reproduzi-lo.

Para fazer isso você deverá utilizar javascript. Algo como abaixo:

```js
var som = document.getElementById("som");

$(".menu div").mouseover(function(){
  som.pause();
  som.currentTime = 0;
  som.play();
});
```

```css
.menu { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.menu > div { 
    background-color:#09F; 
    padding: 20px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 30%;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.menu > div:hover {
    background-color: #0CC;
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div>Botão-1</div>
  <div>Botão-2</div>
  <div>Botão-3</div>
</div>
<audio id="som" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" hidden></audio>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo! :D Só não gostei do som porque fui testar e acharam que tinha um  aqui rss

Comment: @dvd me desculpe por isso! Não achei outro link permanente de mp3 na net. Esse foi o mais fácil! Kkkkkk

Comment: O áudio não executou, estou usando o chrome

Comment: copiei do mesmo jeito que estar aí, mas não executou, mudei até a posição da linha script e inseri dentro do html e mesmo assim não deu

Comment: acabou de executar, só que depois de um click em um espaço em branco e logo depois encostar o mouse em cima o som executa, mas quando abri a página e depois encosta o mouse, ele não executa, estranho....

Comment: Desculpe-me a demora, não estava em meu computador. Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2):

**Toda pagina que reproduz musica deve ter uma alternativa de poder parar**

Sei que não é o foco da pergunta, mas independente disso, também reproduz no mouseover, porém como já foi dito, com CSS parece ser impossivel, pelo menos nos dias atuais.

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //Plays the file when the mouse is over the element
                $("#song12").mouseover (function (){

                    $("#song1")[0].play();
                    $("#song12").html('MouseClick para Pausa');

                });

                //Pause the file when the mouse leaves the element
                 $("#song12").click(function (){

                    $("#song1")[0].pause();
                    $("#song12").html('MouseOver-me para Play');

                });

            });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <audio id="song1" controls style="display:none">
          <source src="http://kithomepage.com/sos/to_nem_ai.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        <button id="song12">MouseOver para Play</button>
```